# When Extending, View invalidate() method does not call OnDraw of Android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-animation, android-custom-view, invalidation

I know similar question has been asked multiple times but most questions answers deal with ViewGroup and not simple View class it self , some suggest to set the setWillNotDraw(false)  this does not work in my case .

```
public class Animated_class extends View {
private Paint paint,paint2,paint3,paint4;
private float percentage;
float fangle;
ObjectAnimator ob;
String month;



public void setPercentage(Float percentage,String month) {
    this.month=month;
    this.percentage=percentage;
    Float p=360f;

  ob=ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this,"fangle",0f,p);
  ob.setDuration(2000);
  ob.start();
}


public void setFangle(float value) {
    Log.e("animation", "setfangle:" +value+" "+fangle);
    this.fangle = value;
   invalidate();
}



public Animated_class(Context context,AttributeSet st) {
    super(context,st);
    setWillNotDraw(false);


    TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
            st,
            R.styleable.Animated_class,
            0, 0);

    try {

        percentage = a.getFloat(R.styleable.Animated_class_percentage, 0);
        month=a.getString(R.styleable.Animated_class_month);
    } finally {
        a.recycle();
    }

    paint2=new Paint();
    paint3=new Paint();
    paint4=new Paint();
    paint4.setTextSize(50);
    paint2.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint3.setAntiAlias(true);

    paint2.setARGB(255,255,255,255);
    paint3.setARGB(255,67,187,118);



}

public Animated_class(Context context) {
    super(context);
    setWillNotDraw (false);

    paint2=new Paint();
    paint3=new Paint();
    paint4=new Paint();
    paint4.setTextSize(50);
    paint2.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint3.setAntiAlias(true);

    paint2.setARGB(255,255,255,255);
    paint3.setARGB(255,67,187,118);





}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
     super.onDraw(canvas);


        RectF rec = new RectF(170, 170, 470, 470);


        canvas.drawArc(rec, 0, fangle, true, paint2);



    Log.e("onDraw", "inside"+fangle);



}
```

}

this is a simple code to animate the formation of a circle by drawing an arc from 0 to 360 degree.

this is my log:

**so here you can see onDraw is only called twice and set method is working fine by setting value of fangle from 0 to 360 but onDraw is not being called .**

```
    04-25 04:34:41.676      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:0.0 0.0
04-25 04:34:41.737      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:0.0 0.0
04-25 04:34:41.902      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:6.1577725 0.0
04-25 04:34:41.908      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/onDraw﹕ inside0.0
04-25 04:34:42.159      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:37.253803 6.1577725
04-25 04:34:42.161      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/onDraw﹕ inside0.0
04-25 04:34:42.179      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:40.232426 37.253803
04-25 04:34:42.183      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:43.126938 40.232426
04-25 04:34:42.200      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:46.29702 43.126938
04-25 04:34:42.216      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:49.562428 46.29702
04-25 04:34:42.234      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:52.720783 49.562428
04-25 04:34:42.250      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:56.164543 52.720783
04-25 04:34:42.267      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:59.696617 56.164543
04-25 04:34:42.285      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:63.099342 59.696617
04-25 04:34:42.301      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:66.79556 63.099342
04-25 04:34:42.318      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:70.57257 66.79556
04-25 04:34:42.333      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:74.19863 70.57257
04-25 04:34:42.350      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:78.12458 74.19863
04-25 04:34:42.366      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:82.12312 78.12458
04-25 04:34:42.384      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:85.95028 82.12312
04-25 04:34:42.400      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:90.08165 85.95028
04-25 04:34:42.417      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:94.27712 90.08165
04-25 04:34:42.434      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:98.281715 94.27712
04-25 04:34:42.451      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:102.59308 98.281715
04-25 04:34:42.467      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:106.959625 102.59308
04-25 04:34:42.483      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:111.11699 106.959625
04-25 04:34:42.500      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:115.58175 111.11699
04-25 04:34:42.517      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:120.09245 115.58175
04-25 04:34:42.533      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:124.37693 120.09245
04-25 04:34:42.550      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:128.96759 124.37693
04-25 04:34:42.568      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:133.5947 128.96759
04-25 04:34:42.583      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:137.97981 133.5947
04-25 04:34:42.600      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:142.66812 137.97981
04-25 04:34:42.617      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:147.38298 142.66812
04-25 04:34:42.633      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:151.84183 147.38298
04-25 04:34:42.650      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:156.59874 151.84183
04-25 04:34:42.668      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:161.37236 156.59874
04-25 04:34:42.683      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:165.87738 161.37236
04-25 04:34:42.700      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:170.67365 165.87738
04-25 04:34:42.716      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:175.47658 170.67365
04-25 04:34:42.733      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:180.0 175.47658
04-25 04:34:42.750      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:184.80605 180.0
04-25 04:34:42.767      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:189.60869 184.80605
04-25 04:34:42.783      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:194.12262 189.60869
04-25 04:34:42.800      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:198.90883 194.12262
04-25 04:34:42.816      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:203.68161 198.90883
04-25 04:34:42.833      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:208.15817 203.68161
04-25 04:34:42.850      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:212.89508 208.15817
04-25 04:34:42.866      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:217.60841 212.89508
04-25 04:34:42.883      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:222.02019 217.60841
04-25 04:34:42.900      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:226.67847 222.02019
04-25 04:34:42.917      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:231.30347 226.67847
04-25 04:34:42.933      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:235.62308 231.30347
04-25 04:34:42.950      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:240.17407 235.62308
04-25 04:34:42.966      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:244.68216 240.17407
04-25 04:34:42.983      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:248.88301 244.68216
04-25 04:34:43.000      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:253.29868 248.88301
04-25 04:34:43.016      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:257.66208 253.29868
04-25 04:34:43.033      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:261.7183 257.66208
04-25 04:34:43.050      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:265.97137 261.7183
04-25 04:34:43.066      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:270.1632 265.97137
04-25 04:34:43.083      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:274.0497 270.1632
04-25 04:34:43.101      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:278.11407 274.0497
04-25 04:34:43.117      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:282.10837 278.11407
04-25 04:34:43.133      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:285.80136 282.10837
04-25 04:34:43.150      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:289.65182 285.80136
04-25 04:34:43.166      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:293.4241 289.65182
04-25 04:34:43.183      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:296.90067 293.4241
04-25 04:34:43.200      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:300.51355 296.90067
04-25 04:34:43.217      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:304.0405 300.51355
04-25 04:34:43.233      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:307.27924 304.0405
04-25 04:34:43.250      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:310.63226 307.27924
04-25 04:34:43.266      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:313.8921 310.63226
04-25 04:34:43.284      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:316.87305 313.8921
04-25 04:34:43.300      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:319.94556 316.87305
04-25 04:34:43.316      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:322.91827 319.94556
04-25 04:34:43.333      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:325.62305 322.91827
04-25 04:34:43.350      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:328.3961 325.62305
04-25 04:34:43.366      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:331.06326 328.3961
04-25 04:34:43.383      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:333.47525 331.06326
04-25 04:34:43.400      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:335.93167 333.47525
04-25 04:34:43.417      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:338.27695 335.93167
04-25 04:34:43.433      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:340.38116 338.27695
04-25 04:34:43.449      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:342.5059 340.38116
04-25 04:34:43.466      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:344.51477 342.5059
04-25 04:34:43.483      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:346.2983 344.51477
04-25 04:34:43.500      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:348.07822 346.2983
04-25 04:34:43.517      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:349.7383 348.07822
04-25 04:34:43.533      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:351.19016 349.7383
04-25 04:34:43.550      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:352.6143 351.19016
04-25 04:34:43.567      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:353.91534 352.6143
04-25 04:34:43.587      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:355.02658 353.91534
04-25 04:34:43.600      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:356.08615 355.02658
04-25 04:34:43.617      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:357.02014 356.08615
04-25 04:34:43.633      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:357.7839 357.02014
04-25 04:34:43.650      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:358.47235 357.7839
04-25 04:34:43.667      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:359.03354 358.47235
04-25 04:34:43.683      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:359.44513 359.03354
04-25 04:34:43.700      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:359.7582 359.44513
04-25 04:34:43.717      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:359.94315 359.7582
04-25 04:34:43.733      473-473/com.example.pulkittyagi.animated_date E/animation﹕ setfangle:360.0 359.94315
```